# ruby string format formatting

Tags: ruby

I have a set of filenames named like the following

```
"file001" "file0001" ...
"file002" "file0002" ...
...
"file100" "file0100" ...
...
```

The pattern is pretty obvious:

```
name, padded_number
```

So if I wanted to use string formatting for the files in the first column I would just write

```
"%s%3d" %[name, number]"
```

But this hardcodes the padding (3). How can I make it so that I can specify the pad as a variable as well and somehow format the provided integer to use the specified padding?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use string interpolation:

```
padding = 9
"%s%#{padding}d" %[name, number]
```

Comment: This results in "file" followed by 8 spaces and a "1".

Comment: Don't you need a `0` in there? `"%s%0#{padding}d"`

Comment: You guys are right but it still answers his *core* question, namely embedding a variable in the format string. Yes, his actually format string needs to be tweaked.

Comment: ```format("%s%0#{padding}d", name, number)``` passes Ruby's style guide validation

Answer (score 9):

```
prefix = "file"
number = "1"
padding = 4
filename = prefix + number.rjust(padding, '0') #=> "file0001"
```